# Python's subprocess.Popen() causes strange indentation of output

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I have some lines of code that gather NMEA sentences from the gpsmon gpsd command line utility (spawned as a child process) and gathers some internal GPS location data from an external radio. I don't want the user to see the gpsmon output in the terminal when they run the code, so I redirect it /dev/null like so:

```
cmd = "gpsmon -n 10.3.1.254:2947 -l output.txt"
gpsmonitor_cmd = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(),stdout = subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

Following this code, I execute a C binary executable from an external file, this as a subprocess as well, as well with it's output redirected to dev null. I'm confused though, as this binary's output still appears in the terminal. The subprocess call in question:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(createBinaryCommand,stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

When I run the code, the output of the binary command looks like this:

```
Duration = 180.0 [sec]
                                                                    01   29.2   1.0  27629867.8   5.0
                                                                                                     02  279.0  22.1  29485316.6   3.1
                                                                                                                                      03   16.2  16.5  29757080.4   3.5
                                                                                                                                                                       04   58.0  48.8  30795329.9   1.9
                  05  222.1  32.8  28015547.1   2.5
                                                   06  307.9  21.2  30581471.1   3.2
                                                                                    07  209.8  81.7  31316191.8   1.5
                                                                                                                     08   75.1  43.6  29817969.2   2.1
                                                                                                                                                      09   59.0  75.3  32009836.6   1.5
```

Very oddly indented. And when I run the code without the code snippet:

```
cmd = "gpsmon -n 10.3.1.254:2947 -l output.txt"
gpsmonitor_cmd = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(),stdout = subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

The output of the C binary command now looks normal again:

```
Duration = 180.0 [sec]
01   29.2   1.0  27629867.8   5.0
02  279.0  22.1  29485316.6   3.1
03   16.2  16.5  29757080.4   3.5
04   58.0  48.8  30795329.9   1.9
05  222.1  32.8  28015547.1   2.5
06  307.9  21.2  30581471.1   3.2
07  209.8  81.7  31316191.8   1.5
08   75.1  43.6  29817969.2   2.1
09   59.0  75.3  32009836.6   1.5
13  247.2  19.4  27856171.3   3.3
14  336.7  38.8  32242259.8   2.2
16  138.9  38.3  27297398.5   2.3
17  349.8   8.4  30063728.5   4.2
18  173.1  12.2  24256737.2   3.9
20  249.7  50.1  30679658.2   1.9
21   46.7   1.5  27617657.0   4.9
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with the back to back child processes being spawned and their output redirecting to dev null, but I cannot figure out how to make the output look normally formatted again.

Comment: Not all output goes to stdout. Some things are written to stderr, some things are written to the terminal. To know how to redirect the content you _want_ to redirect, you need to know how each component of output is being written.

Comment: That said, when you say "the code snippet" -- what _exactly_ are you referring to?

Comment: (also, you have this tagged "linux" -- but out of curiosity, is it _really_ Linux, or is it Microsoft's Linux compatibility layer in Windows? The former is possible, but implies some very unusual terminal settings).

Comment: Not related to your problem, btw, but `cmd.split()` is bad practice. It's much better to explicitly write your command as a list (`cmd = ['gpsmon', '-n', '10.3.1.254:2947', '-l', 'output.txt']`) -- that way you don't get messed up when your output filename contains spaces and `split()` decides to break it into multiple arguments.

Comment: I see, thanks. And this is the VS Code terminal I’m operating in. And by code snippet I meant executing the sub process call for the C executable without the sub process call to gpsmon beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That indentation means you have only newlines without carriage returns, and you're rendering into a terminal that's configured to act in a Windows-y way.

On UNIXy systems, the linefeed character also sends the cursor to the left. On Windowsy systems, it *only* moves the cursor down, and you need a carriage return to send the cursor to the left.

---

To tell a UNIX terminal to treat a linefeed as if it were *both* a carriage return and a linefeed, you can use:

```
stty onlcr
```

Comment: so this could be caused by the fact this output comes from a VS Code terminal?

Comment: I don't expect Microsoft products to ever do _anything_ right, so certainly.

Comment: Strange, I ran it in my normal Ubuntu terminal and the output is still formatted all wonky. I'm able to mostly get around it by putting a carriage return at the end of every string I'm printing, but why would this be causes by the spawning of a child process?

Comment: Depends on what else is going on in the program. Is it maybe using a curses library, or doing something else that can muck around with the TTY settings?

Comment: @ElliottGoldstein, ...reading the gpsmon man page, looks like it _does_ use curses, unless `-a` or `--nocurses` is used. The curses library expects that it's going to be the only thing that writes to the terminal, so it very deliberately configures the TTY to be set up for its own (exclusive) use, assuming nothing else will be trying to write data to that same terminal until after it exits.

Comment: Ok, that does fix the lack of carriage return issue, but now prints to the terminal this output:  TOFF= 1629938529.554690635 real= 1629936718.000000000, which I;m assuming is Time of First Fix

Comment: @ElliottGoldstein, `TZ=UTC date --date=@1629938529.554690635` outputs `Thu 26 Aug 2021 12:42:09 AM UTC` -- that sounds about right to me. Does anything about that output seem wrong to you?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, using a Windows VSCode terminal to a Linux machine. When running a subprocess.Popen, the terminal fails to insert the line feed. Hoping someone has some advice.